# Overloading string operator for key multiset

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, multiset

I would like to overload possibly the string operator of my class so that I can count the number of element inserted into a std::multiset based on the key.
I would like to get the total object of type "a" given the following class:

```
  class Item
{
public:
    Item();
    Item(std::string type, float price);

    friend bool operator <(const Item & lhs, const Item & rhs);

    friend bool operator == (const Item & lhs, const Item & rhs);

    virtual ~Item();

private:
    std::string type_;
    float price_;
};

bool operator<(const Item & lhs, const Item & rhs)
{
    return (lhs.price_ < rhs.price_);
}

bool operator == (const Item & lhs, const Item & rhs)
{
    return (lhs.type_ == rhs.type_);
}

 int   main(){
        Item a("a", 99999);
        Item b("b", 2);
        Item c("c", 5);
        Item d("d", 5);
        Item e("e", 555);
        Item f("f", 568);
        Item g("a", 99999);

    std::multiset <Item> items_;

    items_.insert(a);
    items_.insert(b);
    items_.insert(c);
    items_.insert(d);
    items_.insert(g);
    items_.insert(a);

    auto tota = items_.count("a");

    return 0;
    }
```

And I would expect `tota` to return 2 in this case.
However I am not sure to know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
auto tota = items_.count("a");
```

use

```
auto tota = items_.count(Item("a", 0));
```

The price can be anything since you don't use it in the `operator<` function.

---

I misspoke about the `operator<` function. It **IS** using price. If you want to be able to lookup by just the type, you need to change it to:

```
bool operator<(const Item & lhs, const Item & rhs)
{
   return (lhs.type_ < rhs.type_);
}
```

---

If you want to be able to search for `Item`s using just a string, you might want to use a `std::multimap<std::string, Item>` instead of `std::multiset<Item>`.

Comment: in the ==operator function you mean?

Comment: I also wanted to avoid the creation of an object for that, but I dont know if it is possible in this case...

Comment: @trexgris, no. `std::multiset` doesn't use `operator==`. It needs only `operator<`.

Comment: Is there still a way to avoid the creation of an object to check the range of items of type "a" or simply get the count?

Comment: @trexgris, I don't think there is any way to avoid creating the object.